# Why appear undefined in the end of for-loop in JavaScript when I try to prints out layers of stars?

Tags: javascript

I try to write a function called "stars" which prints out layers of stars in the following pattern:

```
stars(1);
// *
stars(4);
// *
// **
// ***
// ****
```

this is my code:

```
function stars(n){
   let result="";
   for(let i=1;i<=n;i++){
    result +="*" ;
    console.log(result);
     }
}
console.log(stars(1));
console.log(stars(4));
```

but, it turns out to be:

```
"*"
undefined

"*"
"**"
"***"
"****"
undefined
```

I try to take apart the loop but still can't figure out why the "undefined" appeared.
Thanks!

Comment: That's just what the function returns. If you don't want to see it, call `stars` without `console.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function stars(n){
    let result="";
    for(let i=1;i<=n;i++){
        result +="*" ;
        console.log(result);
    }
}
stars(1);
stars(4);
```

stars is a function that returns nothing, then console logging it logs undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should just call stars(x),Instead of using console.Because your function doesn't return anything。